# How can I spoof the Mimetype of a file upload?

Tags: file-upload

There are posts that says php mimetype isn't secure, or can be bypassed. How do people spoof the mimetype?

Comment: Which function are you using to try and determine the type of the uploaded file?

Comment: PHP: mimetype($file)

Comment: There isn't any standard function called `mimetype`, do you mean `mime_content_type`?

Comment: Oh wait sorry its getimagesize

Answer (score 6):

If you were creating the header on the upload request programmatically, you can declare the headers, etc. [An explanation](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/file-upload-vulnerabilities/) which includes some code samples.

You should go beyond the mime type and check the content. E.g., if you allow an image upload, do a conversion of the image on the server and do other checks as well.

You may want to check out this [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028184/mime-type-spoofing):

> The "signature headers" help you to decide what kind of image format a
>   file tries to impersonate. In a next step you could check if the rest
>   of the contents are compliant with the underlying image format. This
>   would guarantee you that the file is really an image file of that
>   specific format.

You may also be interested in this [article on GIFAR](http://www.infoworld.com/d/security-central/photo-can-steal-your-online-credentials-306):

> They call this type of file a GIFAR, a contraction of GIF and JAR, the
>   two file types that are mixed. At Black Hat, the researchers will show
>   attendees how to create the GIFAR while omitting a few key details to
>   prevent it from being used immediately in any widespread attack.
>
> To the Web server, the file looks exactly like a .gif file, however a
>   browser's Java virtual machine will open it up as a Java Archive file
>   and then run it as an applet. That gives the attacker an opportunity
>   to run Java code in the victim's browser. For its part, the browser
>   treats this malicious applet as though it were written by the Web
>   site's developers.